# docker network connect to host second interface

Tags: networking, docker

I have a use-case where my Docker container's second interface needs to share the interface of the host's second network interface. Is this possible using `docker network connect`? If so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

> May not be **the** answer, but a bit too long to explain in a comment

---

If I were you I would:

#### Start the container with `--net=host`

Start up the container by sharing the host stack IP:

```
user@host:~$ docker run --name=c0 --net=host docker-image
```

#### Plug it in into the network

With the command

```
user@host:~$ docker network connect mynet c0
```

But I just tried it and here is the error message:

> Error response from daemon: Container sharing network namespace with another container or host cannot be connected to any other network

As this is not working I guess it is not (yet?) possible. I suggest you to work around your need of the host stack IP (which must be consider as insecure btw).

Why do you **need** the host stack IP?

Comment: I only need the second interface on the host, not the whole stack. Normally, the second interface(or the second ip) is a management ip which whitelisted by another external service(which cannot be dockerized) which is sitting in another server. But it was a very good suggestion although it may not work yet.

Comment: Using the option `--publish` you can select an host-ip.